# Problem with redirection in python appengine

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I am trying to create some alias ::

```
util.run_wsgi_app(webapp.WSGIApplication([
    (r"/(.{1,2})", MainPage)
], debug=debug)

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
def get(self,token):
    token_dict = {
        'fb':'http://www.facebook.com/anilashanbhag',
        '+' :'http://plus.google.com/106274357148468411814',
        't' :'http://twitter.com/masteranil'
    }
    logging.debug(token)
    if token in token_dict:
        self.redirect(token_dict[token])
    else:
        self.redirect('/')
```

The problem is that fb and t work but + doesnt. I was thinking appengine is encoding the url but then logs show 
/+ 404 ....

Comment: Hav you tried replacing `'+'` with `urlencode('+')`?

Comment: It doesnt work . Well i am not sure of what token is entering the get function or if at all its entering

Answer (score 3):

The + is a reserved character outlined in [RFC 1738 - Uniform Resource Locators (URL) specification](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm). It's reserved because it is used as part of the delimiter syntax in URL's. Try URL Encoding your character (%2B) and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok so if you see my rule it is .{1,2} . If i explicitly wanted + it would have been \+ . I have tried %2B but doesnt work

Comment: "%2B" is 3 characters; if that's indeed what your application is receiving, the 404 is because the handler doesn't match more than 2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for the sake of completion : The correct answer is :: 
"%2B" is 3 characters; this is what application is receiving, the 404 is because the handler doesn't match more than 2.